# NSNumberFormatter crashing iPhone SDK 4.0b2

Tags: iphone, crash, nsnumberformatter

I've got an app that's been in the app store for a while and functions perfectly on OS 3.1 - 3.13.  However, when tested on 4.0b2 I noticed that it crashes in the same place every time, but only on the device, never on the simulator.  I'm using a 3GS to test.

On loadView I initialize an NSNumberFormatter object which is declared and retained in the interface so I have access to it everywhere.  In my method I call it several times to convert string values into nsnumbers to be stored in a mutable dictionary.

Here's an example:

```
[myDictionary setObject:[myStyleFormatter numberFromString:@"1"] forKey:@"hours"];
[myDictionary setObject:[myStyleFormatter numberFromString:@"30"] forKey:@"minutes"];
[myDictionary setObject:[myStyleFormatter numberFromString:@"10"] forKey:@"seconds"];
```

For some reason it crashes as soon as it tries to set hours.  The error is "attempt to insert nil value (key: hours)"

Have I been doing something wrong all along?  Has the api changed for 4.0b2?

Thanks,

Howie

Comment: First check whether the problem is in `numberForString:` (returning `nil`) or in `setObject:` (not accepting a valid object)?

Comment: This SDK is under an NDA. You'd be better off asking on the Apple Developer Forums anyway, where the 4.0 SDK is being actively discussed: http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: Also, if this is a real bug with the SDK, file a report at https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tracked it down to a `NSNumberFormatter` statement that did not like spaces (or commas) every 3 digits in the numbers. Which is one of the reasons for having a `number formatter`.

```
NSNumber *number = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:mstring];
```

It is fairly standard code in many examples on the internet, so I suspect a lot will find the problem.

Anyway, I fixed it by getting rid of the spaces

```
NSArray *sArray = [mstring componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
[mstring setString:@" "]; //space at beginning is OK, would prefer nil
for (NSString *sElement in sArray) {
    [mstring appendString:sElement];
}
```

Then the `currencyFormatter` line worked.

BUT, in another area of my code, that same `currencyFormatter` statement worked with no problem. I tried changing code in the area to cause the problem, but I could not.

So, very curious!!!